# Get Midi Messages in Java while sequencer playing

Tags: java, midi

basically, i want to be able to see an event handler on the ShortMessage component (for ON_NOTE and OFF_NOTE). Or, from the track, how to view all the events by the tick number (not some vector index?)

basically a great way to show the current note playing Live, while it its actually playing on the screen

Comment: If this is just for debugging purposes, MIDI-OX is a great too for this.

Comment: currently im just using the basic internal MiDi configuration. No external midi devices. IT seems so simple , but for some reason its taken me forever, and i still can't figure it out.